# How to send sms to user using msg91 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written the api call like this:

```
 var response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse("http://api.msg91.com/api/v2/sendsms"),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "authkey": "API key"
  },
  body: jsonEncode({
    "sender": "note",
    "route": "4",
    "country": "91",
    "flash": 1,
    "sms": 
      {"message": "Message1", "to": "9999999999"}
  }),
);
```

But this giving me error : {type: error, message: Invalid content type.Please send data in formdata,application/xml,application/json format, code: }

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing theses

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

or replace it with

```
"Content-Type": "application/xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use multipart/form-data as content-type ->

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
```